# Measure bandwidth usage (GB's transferred) on a linux server

Tags: linux, monitoring, bandwidth, performance-monitoring

I have a linux email server that I am thinking about moving into "the cloud". After investigating the pricing I see that my major cost is going to be in bandwidth. How would you guys suggest measuring the total amount of data transferred over a period of time?

Comment: What distribution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have successfully ran [vnstat](http://humdi.net/vnstat/) on servers in the past. It's avaliable packged for fedora & ubuntu (and probably other distros). There is also a [php frontend](http://www.sqweek.com/sqweek/index.php?p=1) avaliable that's very easy to setup.

Comment: thanks! vnstat shows me just what I need. Very easy setup for vnstat and the php frontend.

Answer (score 3):

- `ifconfig` tells you the usage for an interface, including the amount of data transferred.
- [ntop](http://www.ntop.org/ntop.html) logs and analyses traffic in a lot of ways.
- [iftop](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/iftop/) and [iptraf](http://iptraf.seul.org/) show you connections and other data at real time

Comment: Check out bandwidthd as well.

http://bandwidthd.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 3):

If you want the low tech version, you could just cat /proc/net/dev record the time, and then do it again, and calculate it from that.  However, be aware that the counter wraps around at 2^32 bytes (4GB) (at least on my recent 32-bit kernels):

```
Inter-|   Receive                                                |  Transmit
 face |bytes    packets errs drop fifo frame compressed multicast|bytes    packets errs drop fifo colls carrier compressed
    lo:   51433     617    0    0    0     0          0         0    51433     617    0    0    0     0       0          0
  eth0:3270597247 14887385    0    0    0     0          0         0 694109632 7720886    0    0    0     0       0          0
  pan0:       0       0    0    0    0     0          0         0        0       0    0    0    0     0       0          0
```

There is a perl routine to parse this in this blog post of mine: [Debuging a script that parses /proc/net/dev](http://www.kbrandt.com/2009/07/debuging-a-script-that-parses-procnetdev.html)

Comment: +1 for simplicity and availability.  Nice.

Answer (score 1):

Run sysstat on your server through cron; the network information (`sar -n ALL`) will give you rxkB/s and txkB/s which you can easily turn into a total traffic figure.

Answer (score 1):

snmp + mrtg / rrdtool (cacti)

Answer (score 1):

As someone else mentioned, [vnstat](http://humdi.net/vnstat/) is a great tool that's easy to setup and should easily give you the information you need.

Note tho, your provider should give you a view into the tool they're using for bandwidth billing.  There are multiple ways to track and bill for bandwidth usage (switch port measurements vs. virtual machine counters, 95% percentile vs. total bits sent, sent and received vs. sent only) that will have a substantial impact on your ultimate billing - it's quite important to base things off of the tool that they're using for billing in order to get a true picture of what your bandwidth costs will be.  This way, you can accurately take action to shift or minimize your bandwidth usage before you get hit with a major bill for bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

munin has a basic plugin for networkusage

Answer (score 0):

I use [collectd](http://collectd.org/) to collect interface traffic counts, amongst other things, and a slightly altered version of [this script](http://haroon.sis.utoronto.ca/rrd/scripts/) to generate pretty graphs and counts. The output looks something like [this](http://olm.spillett.net/cgi-bin/rrd.cgi/olm.spillett.net/net_all.html) though is quite variable if you have specific preferences as you can see from the [rrdtool gallery](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/gallery/index.en.html). If you need more detail than simple interface traffic counts, then you can use the iptables module from collectd to count more specific traffic groups.